# Combo box populating a DIV using ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is a good technique (in 2016) to allow dynamic population of a Wordpress page?

Basically I have to dynamically load a DIV in the webpage depending on selection of a combo box.

BTW, are there any pitfalls to avoid in a Wordpress environment?

Thanks

Comment: You have 3 options, to use the built-in `wp-ajax.php` functionality, to make your own `ajax.php` and to load `wp-load.php` file in the beginning of your page, but among the 3 of them, I think using your own `ajax` source is the best practice..
Anything beyond that is standard in wordpress IMO.

Comment: I'd love to answer this but it's a little vague. Are you looking for an example? I've done this a couple of ways. Are you loading local (wp) content or remote content ? The pitfalls I've found relate mostly to content origin.

Comment: Local content. Basically the page will have a combo box that will allow users in the front end to load selected/filtered posts (in a list). I am aware about dozens plugins/widgets that will do this, but my request is for a particularly customized scenario, hence the combobox that will trigger filtered post-list loading

Comment: Who knows maybe @dg4220 may post an Answer on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how you're populating your combo box, here's how I would do it:
Use jQuery to capture the form selection:

```
jQuery('#formElementID').change(function () {//this captures dropdown menu change event
  //call js function and pass form value - in my case a post id
   fetchTenantWoContactInfo(jQuery('#formElementID').val());
});
```

Use function to call ajax function to get post info

```
function fetchTenantWoContactInfo(unitID) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://apexpropertymanagement-me.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: { fgpsnunitID: unitID, action: 'getOccupantsTemplate' },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('.current-wo-contact-info').replaceWith('<div class="current-wo-contact-info">' + data + '</div>');
            },

        });

    }
```

In your functions file add the below php function and return the result. I'm returning mostly post_meta data here but the point is to assemble and echo your content string. Then in the 'success' area of your ajax call replace the designated div area in your template. In my case `<div class="current-wo-contact-info"></div>`

```
function getOccupantsTemplate_fn() {

   global $wpdb;
   $occ_ids = get_post_meta( $_POST['fgpsnunitID'], 'fgpsn_property_unit_occupant_id', true );
    //echo substr($occ_ids, 0, (strlen($occ_ids)-1) );
    //fgpsn_property_unit_occupant_id
    if ( isset($occ_ids) && !is_null($occ_ids) && !empty($occ_ids) ) {
        if (is_array($occ_ids)) {
          $cur_occupants = '';

            $i = 0;
            foreach($occ_ids as $k=>$v) {
              if ($v != '') {

                $cur_occupants .=  get_post_meta( $occ_ids[$i], 'fgpsn_contact_last_name', true ) . ',
                 ' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids[$i], 'fgpsn_contact_first_name', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Phone: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids[$i], 'fgpsn_contact_phone', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Email: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids[$i], 'fgpsn_contact_email', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Cell: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids[$i], 'fgpsn_contact_cell_phone', true ) . '<br>';
                $i++;
              } 

            }
        } else {

                $cur_occupants .=  get_post_meta( $occ_ids, 'fgpsn_contact_last_name', true ) . ',
                 ' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids, 'fgpsn_contact_first_name', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Phone: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids, 'fgpsn_contact_phone', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Email: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids, 'fgpsn_contact_email', true ) . '<br>
                <b>Cell: </b>' . get_post_meta( $occ_ids, 'fgpsn_contact_cell_phone', true ) . '<br>';

        }
  }
  $cur_occupants = substr( $cur_occupants, 0, (strlen($cur_occupants)-1) );
  echo $contacts . $cur_occupants;
  //return or print text? html since i dont need to have an array or mehu
  //echo $cur_occupants;
}
```

Finally, you need to give ajax access to your php function.:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getOccupantsTemplate', 'getOccupantsTemplate_fn');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getOccupantsTemplate', 'getOccupantsTemplate_fn');
```